# iOS - Using Cocoapods objective-C within Swift Code

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to add an objective-C/CocoaPods code ([GBFlatButton](https://github.com/barbosa/GBFlatButton)) to an existing swift code. I read all about I found regarding Header settings and I did this, let me know if is well performed.

[Header Bridging configuration](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6jcoviowyxwlw8/header-bridge.png?dl=0)

Also the Header file has the right import files added to it.

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GBFlatButton/GBFlatButton.h>
#import <GBFlatButton/UIColor+GBFlatButton.h>
```

On the other hand the CocoaPods project doesn't give me an error when I compile the code. The error occurs when I use the button, maybe is the way I'm trying to use this objective-c code:

```
let MyButton: GBFlatButton! = GBFlatButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200.0, height: 40.0))
```

Also I tried to use it like this: `@IBOutlet var FButton: GBFlatButton!`

This is the final error I have:

> /Users//Documents/Projects/party/party/party/partyStepViewController.swift:18:19:
>   Use of undeclared type 'GBFlatButton'
>
> /Users//Documents/Projects/party/party/party/partyStepViewController.swift:18:9:
>   Could not infer type for 'MyButton'

Any clue will help :)

Thanks!!, if you need more info don't hesitate to ask me.

Comment: I add the the following code inside the swift code: import GBFlatButton . With this works fine. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

you forgot to add the **bridging header** in the Build settings of the app

[image]

In ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button: GBFlatButton! = GBFlatButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50))
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

just do this and then it will work